# Ubuntu Dell XPS 15 9570 Audio problem

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04

Hi I have the laptop in title and I'm experiencing some issues with audio. When i turn on my computer the speakers I've connected (working fine with a Lenovo thinkpad with ubuntu) make some noise, like a distorpted amplifier,  this noise disappears as soon as I touch the volume settings. In 
/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf I've added a conf string(options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi) who I've found here related to my problem but without any type of positive result.
Some suggestions?
P.S. I've also installed pulseaudio.